# Why it shows the error: Error: Target container is not a DOM element, when creating a ReactDOM.createPortal() and pass a const variable

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-context

On a tutorial about ReactJS and context API, I was trying to render a Modal class by creating a const inside a class extended by React.Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.scss';
import { AppContext } from '../../context/appContext';

class Modal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const node = (
            <div
                className="modal-container">
                <div className="modal">
                    <h1>modal</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        return ReactDOM.createPortal(node, document.getElementById('modal'));
    }
}

Modal.contextType = AppContext;

export default Modal;
```

And using this class on a layout class also extended of React.Component and using the ReactDOM by

```
import Modal from '../modal';
<Modal />
```

But when I tried to render it, it gave me the error that the const node I created, it's not a DOM element, also on the tutorial I followed to do this, he hasn't any error.

```
Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
createPortal$$1 [as createPortal]
> 17 |         return ReactDOM.createPortal(node, document.getElementById('modal'));
View compiled
▶ 16 stack frames were collapsed.
```

Comment: have you tried making node as a function? `const node = () => <div ... `

Comment: Are you rendering it into html that has an element with id of "modal"? Or are you creating that element somewhere else?

Comment: On a layout class extended of a React.Component I'm using it by importing it
import Modal from '../modal';
<Modal />

Comment: Defining `node` in `render()` does not mean it has been created and exists in the DOM. Your error is because you're attempting to mount to an element that doesn't exist. You need to create your modal `div` in a parent component or define it in a HTML document that bootstraps your React app.